# Facebook login button has gone mad in IE! It's all over the page

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

Has anyone seen this before. It works perfectly in Chrome, Safari, FF etc. It's like it's a background image that does not recognise the constraints of it's containing div. I put the div around it to constrain it but no difference.

http://nicerworld.com/static/images/ie_error.png

```
<div style="width:200px;height:25px;"><fb:login-button registration-url="http://nicerworld.com/fb_reg_step_1/" on-login="fb_login(arguments);">{% trans "login with Facebook" %}</fb></div>
```

I hate IE so much it's not funny!

Hope one of you can stop me doing something silly!

Answer (score 0):

The </fb> on the end was the problem. It should have been </fb:login-button>!!

It worked in all other browsers. As usual, MS cost me loads of time.

Rich